# EPPlus: How to update Pivot Table SourceRange

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, epplus

I'm getting stuck trying to update the SourceRange of a Pivot-Table with EPPLus inside a C# class.
I've found that CacheDefinition.SourceRange contains the DataSource of my **existing** Pivot-Table but I don't know how to change it.
Existing Pivot-Table datasource is a range on a data worksheet in the same Excel file.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance,
Alessandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

You can create a self-dimensioning defined name that encompasses your data range. I use this all the time.

Open Name Manager.

Click New.

Enter a Name for your range.

Put the following in the Refers to: line

OFFSET(DataSource!`$A$1`,0,0,COUNTA(DataSource!$A:$A),COUNTA(DataSource!$1:$1))

syntax: OFFSET(reference, rows, cols, [height], [width])

Substitute your sheet/tab name for DataSource. This assumes that the table starts in A1 (first section) and you that you want a defined name as long as the number of values in column A and as wide as the values in row 1. It is a very flexible and useful method for making sure your defined names encompass all the data on the sheet.

Comment: Thanks Tim, It works but introduces a new problem... It seems that EPPLus cannot save the file if a dynamic defined name is present. 
Error is: 
Exception: Error saving file 
Stack Trace:    in OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.Save()

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance,
Alessandro

Comment: I got the exact same problem you do, did you manage to fix it?